# xcode secure text field how to get the password typed in there?

Tags: swift, xcode, appkit

```
@IBOutlet weak var button: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var password: NSSecureTextField!
@IBAction func buttonclick(_ sender: Any) {
   if(password.text == "test"){

   }
}
```

this said it didn't work or something
now I want it to check if the password is like test and then it enters
but now i tried to do it like the normal text box but it wouldn't work ether

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Replace with**

```
if password.stringValue == "test" {
        print("correct")
    }
```

Comment: It’s my pleasure to help you